# how to transfer more then one string from one activity to another in android

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-xml

i have to transfer more then one string from one activity to another activity in android , i already know how to transfer one string from one to another string in android but for more then one string i can not found ways my code is here ,

```
 if (long_insert_row_index>0){
                        //Spinner spDepCMPName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spDepCMPName);
                        // String strCMP= spDepCMPName.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        //String strCMP=depositecmpname;

           //startActivity(new Intent(DepositActivity.this, AuditPointDetailsActivity.class).putExtra("insert_row_index",""+long_insert_row_index).putExtra("segment_name", spinner_segment.getSelectedItem().toString()).putExtra("audit_type_name", spinner_audit_type.getSelectedItem().toString()).putExtra("audit_type_id", audit_type_id).putExtra("segment_id", segment_id));


///please see commented section at bottom
                      startActivity(new Intent(DepositActivity.this, DepositeNextActivity.class)
                                .putExtra("insert_row_index",""+long_insert_row_index)
                                .putExtra("CMPName", depositecmpname));
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(DepositActivity.this,"Error while inserting data.Please re-enter data.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
```

Now i want to send both string from one activity to another , i dont know how to do that one .

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use code in your first activity like :-

```
  ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    arr.add(long_insert_row_index);
    arr.add( depositecmpname);
    Intent intent = new Intent(firstactivity.this,secondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("array_list", arr);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Now in another class you can use this code saying :-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>)extras.getStringArrayList("array_list");
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+arr.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Use for open activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("String1", "Hello!");
            intent.putExtra("String2", "Hello!2")
            activity.startActivity(intent);
```

In open activity:

```
getIntent.getStringExtra("String1");
getIntent.getStringExtra("String2");
```

Or use

```
intent.putExtra("StringByteArr", "str".toByteArray());
```

and:

```
String.valueOf(getIntent.getByteArrayExtra("StringByteArr"));
```